# find last 4 digits of a given number using Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 10 digit telephone number.
I need to find the last 4 digits of a given number using Angular Js.

Is there any way to find the given number.

EG: 9916983265

Answer (score 3):

If your telephone number is a String

```
var telNb = "9916983265";
var last4Digits = telNb.substring(telNb.length-4, telNb.length);
```

If your telephone number is an integer :

```
var telNb = 9916983265;
var last4Digits = telNb % 10000;
```